# 'Do No Harm' quest stuck

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, there is a quest early in the game given by Dr. Zed in Sanctuary called "Do No Harm".

I am on the part of the quest where I am supposed to bring an eridium shard to Dr. Tannis.   When I speak with her, the objective is marked as complete, but the quest does not continue, and seems to be stuck.   Talking to Tannis or Zed causes them both to say something like "do you have any progress updates?".

Is this a bug, or is there some objective that I am missing?   Is there a way to un-stick it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this thread and especially post #38. I have quoted it below.
http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=2778730

> Alright, I have a fix ready for QA and if all goes well it will be included in a future update. This fix will prevent the bug from happening and for those already hit by this issue it will automatically make the quest ready to turn in.
>   In the meantime,
>   - To avoid this issue be sure the Tannis cut scene plays *before* you talk her.
>   - To workaround this issue join another player's game and complete this quest with them.